# WPF Bind item source for ListBox through xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="phonesList" SelectionChanged="phonesList_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Phones}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="5">
                    <Image Width="100" Height="75" Source="{Binding Path=ImagePath}" />
                    <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Path=Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Path=Company}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Phones = new ObservableCollection<Phone>
        {
            new Phone {Id=1, ImagePath="/Images/iphone6s.jpg", Title="iPhone 6S", Company="Apple" },
            new Phone {Id=2, ImagePath="/Images/lumia950.jpg", Title="Lumia 950", Company="Microsoft" },
            new Phone {Id=3, ImagePath="/Images/nexus5x.jpg", Title="Nexus 5X", Company="Google" },
            new Phone {Id=4, ImagePath="/Images/galaxys6.jpg", Title="Galaxy S6", Company="Samsung"}
        };
            //phonesList.ItemsSource = Phones;
    }

    private void phonesList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Phone p = (Phone)phonesList.SelectedItem;
        MessageBox.Show(p.Title);
    }
}
```

I need to connect Phones to ListBox. I can do it through the commented line phonesList.ItemsSource = Phones. However, when I tried to bind it via xaml (`ItemsSource="{Binding Phones}"`), nothing has happened.

How should I bind list to this ListBox through xaml?

Comment: `DataContext = this;`. Take a look at [Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0).

Answer (score 0):

`Binding` works on `DataContext` (of your view or your window) per default. (Consider switching to the MVVM pattern.)

Having said that, binding allows to choose which source to bind to with the `Source` property or the `RelativeSource`. `RelativeSource` is used with the `RelativeSourceExtension`. Set the `Mode` to `FindAncestor` and the `AncestorType` to `Window` to set the source to your `Window`. This way `BindingExtension` is able to resolve `Phones`, for it is a property of your window.

```xml
<ListBox ... ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Phones, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}">
```